# Postgres COPY importing wrong character for ñ

Tags: postgresql, unix, encoding

Wrong characters are shown in Postgres Database when I do a COPY of a csv file with the encoding WIN1252.

It works fine in postgres database 11.3 with datcollate and datctype encodings en_US.UTF8 and es_ES.UTF8, in both databases ñ character is show correctly after COPY.

It doesn´t work in postgres database 9.4.9 with datcollate and datctype encodings en_US.UTF8

This is the COPY sql instruction that I´m using:

`COPY tmp_divisionzonaUE(Id,version,COMPAÑIA,COD_UE,UNIDAD_EJECUCION,DIVISION,COD_UG,U_GESTION,COD_UC,U_COORDINACION,UE_PROVINCIA,UE_DIRECCION,UE_CP,UE_AREA_DESPLIEGE,UE_COD_SIEMENS,UE_COD_TERRITORIO,UE_COD_DIVISION,UE_COD_PROVINCIA,UE_COD_LOCALIDAD)"+ " FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT TEXT, ENCODING 'WIN1252', DELIMITER ';'," + " HEADER false)`

UPDATE: I have check that the problem is where I launch COPY code, if I launch  it windows machine and csv file is storage in windows machine ñ characters are shown correctly in the database but if I launch COPY code in linux machine and csv file is storage in linux machine ñ characters are not shown correctly.

UPDATE2: In linux machine if I launch COPY from eclipse (because it is inside Java code) the ñ character appear well in database but If I launch the same jar file in the command line with `java -jar filename` the ñ characters doesn´t appear well.

Comment: "*Doesn't work*" is not a problem description. What character do you get instead? What is actually in the file?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to identify the bytes in the file you are loading. A commend like `od -t x1 filename` can be helpful.

Comment: @melpomene I get CATALUï¿½A ESTE instead of CATALUÑA ESTE

Comment: Might be UTF-8 misinterpreted as Windows-1252. What is actually in that file?

Comment: @melpomene The file is a csv file separated by ; and each line is like CATALUÑA ESTE;2;3;7

Comment: @melpomene The copy code is inside Java program. If I launch this Java program in eclipse in Linux machine ñ characters appear well in database but if a launch the same class in a jar file from command line ñ characters appears wrong

Comment: No, I need to see the actual data, preferably in form of a hex dump (as Laurenz said).

Comment: If the problem is with a Java program, you'll have to post the Java code.

Comment: @melpomene I don´t think so the problem is in the Java code because the Java code only execute the COPY SQL I have posted. I don´t know the reason why if I launch it eclipse it works but If I launch the jar file doesn´t

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the encoding of the file in the `ENCODING` option of the [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-copy.html) command.

> `ENCODING`
>
> Specifies that the file is encoded in the `encoding_name`. If this option is omitted, the current client encoding is used. See the Notes below for more details.

Comment: I had done it, I put ENCODING 'WIN1252' but if I launch the jar in the command line ñ characters still appear wrong.

Comment: Is the file in `WINDOWS-1252` encoding? What do you get if you `SELECT bad_column::bytea FROM bad_table WHERE ...`, that is, cast the "bad" value to `bytea`? That will show the actual bytes, so we can find out what is going on.